# Trivial Graph theory questions

Tags: graph-theory

1. Can every disconnected graph be decomposed into 2 disjoint subgraphs ? If yes then edge-disjoint or vertex-disjoint ? and Why ?
   If not then what are the exceptions ?
2. Given n vertices is it always possible to draw edges such that the graph has a hamiltonian circuit ?
3. Can we say that every connected graph is either an Euler graph or an unicursal graph ?

PS:I am fairly new to Graph Theory, and I am learning on my own. Please don't mind if the question is not technically correct. I just want to get the concepts clear.

Comment: Always keep in mind the following examples: complete graphs (particularly $K_2$ through $K_4$), the $n$-cycle (particularly the 5-cycle), the $n$-path, and to a lesser extent the Petersen graph. These are excellent graphs for testing intuition about any particular property. Here, $K_2$ disproves 2 (albeit for trivial reasons), and $K_4$ disproves 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, we pick a vertex, and make its connected component is one subgraph, and make the rest of the graph the other subgraph.  (Note: the second subgraph might not be connected.)

   These two subgraphs are both vertex-disjoint (don't have a common vertex) and edge-disjoint (don't have a common edge).
2. Yes for $n \geq 3$ vertices.  If the vertices are $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, then the edges $12, 23, \ldots, (n-1)n, n1$ form a Hamilton circuit.
3. No: for example, consider this graph:

[[image: <span class=]$K_{1,5}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq2v4.png)

Whenever we reach a leaf vertex (a vertex of degree $1$), if we must continue walking, we retrace its corresponding edge.